# how to represent a list of entity values in JSON object

Tags: java, json, servlets

I have a list of records in a entity type ,i had a confusion the way how to represent in column wise list or each of record as a `json` object,that means list of `JSON` Objects.

**::Explanation ::**

Here `firstName`,`secondName`,`thirdName` are `column names`.
Need To Represent Like this format

__`{{firstName:Rec1,secondName:Rec1,thirdName:Rec1},{firstName:Rec2,secondName:Rec2,thirdName:Rec2}...n}__`

But i approached like

_`_{firstName:[Rec1,Rec2,Rec3...],secondName:[Rec1,Rec2,Rec3...],thirdName:[Rec1,Rec2,Rec3...]},__`

When i tried to pass as a entity type means it shows like

```
 __{"ServiceData":[com.aiway.eea.ejb.to.student.ParentStudentDetailsTO@8b0db2,com.aiway.eea.ejb.to.student.ParentStudentDetailsTO@1304967]}__
```

Please Help me to solve this...

Comment: You can try [ { "firstName" : "Rec1" , "secondName" : "Rec1", "thirdName : "Rec1" }, {  "firstName" : "Rec2" , "secondName" : "Rec2", "thirdName : "Rec2" } ]. This JSON denotes an array consisting of 2 objects.

Comment: Do you have a `toString()` method for the `ParentStudentDetailsTO`class ? Not really clear what you have, what you get and what you want to get. Probably you should post some code and say what JSON lib do you use.

Comment: @PeterMmm ,i did not use any toString() in inside of TO

Comment: @dsp_user as per syntax ur given,data Like {"ServiceData":[{"parentId":4009,"parentRelation":"Father","parentNotification":false,"parentOccupation":"bussiness","parentEducation":"mba","parentName":"tharun"},{"parentId":4010,"parentRelation":"Mother","parentNotification":false,"parentOccupation":"sdfsdf","parentEducation":"sdfsdfs","parentName":"rakshitha"}]}  **Then how will i retrive by name?,,Or if possible to pass as a Entity type?**

Comment: You need to use an object mapper (e.g. Jackson) to convert that JSON string into a Java POJO. You will still need to create the POJO manually. If I find time later, I'll provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

we not able to pass as a entity type,we need Transfer Object to convert from ENTITY to JSON object,if **List entityType** means then Use **List JSONObject** and then put that List of JsonObject to another Json object like <"serviceData":JsonObject> then it will OUTPUT like 
 **{"ServiceData":[{"parentId":4009,"parentRelation":"Father","‌​parentNotification":‌​false,"parentOccupat‌​ion":"bussiness","pa‌​rentEducation":"mba"‌​,"parentName":"tharu‌​n"},{"parentId":4010‌​,"parentRelation":"M‌​other","parentNotifi‌​cation":false,"paren‌​tOccupation":"sdfsdf‌​","parentEducation":‌​"sdfsdfs","parentNam‌​e":"rakshitha"}]}**

You can retrive like the Example syntax
[See The Example From this IMAGE Link....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XG9z7.png)

use this Link to lean about JSON Array
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp